# "of" or "in" image

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wrote:

> For this purpose, a certain area **in** the image that covers the top edge is identified. Then, a curve is fitted through the white pixels **in** this area.

However, it could be written as:

> For this purpose, a certain area **of** the image that covers the top edge is identified. Then, a curve is fitted through the white pixels **of** this area.

I myself prefer "in". For example, the white pixels are in this area rather than to belong to it.

Anyway, which is better here, and in general, when "in" is preferred to "of"?

Answer (score 2):

> For this purpose, a certain area **of** the image that covers the top edge is identified. Then, a curve is fitted through the white pixels **in** this area.

[*of*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of_1):

> 4. constituted by, containing, or characterized by

and [*in*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in_1):

> 7. expressing a ratio, proportion, or probability

where for example there are 1000 white pixels in the picture containing 5000 pixels.